# Track How Long a User Has Been Logged In

Tags: php, html, session, cookies, time

I am currently trying to figure out how to time how long a user has been logged on my website, and then display the time.

Essentially, when the user logs in, I need a way to record the time they logged on, and then on another page of my site, I want to show them how long they've been logged in. How would I go about doing this using cookies or session variables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would store the time they logged in as a session variable like

```
$_SESSION['loginTime'] = new DateTime(date('y-m-d h:m:s'));
```

Then calculate the difference with `diff`.

Get the current time

```
$difference= $_SESSION['loginTime']->diff(new DateTime(date('y-m-d h:m:s')));
```

Then you can output time since with these methods

```
echo $difference->y; //return the difference in Year(s).
echo $difference->m; //return the difference in Month(s).
echo $difference->d; //return the difference in Day(s).
echo $difference->h; //return the difference in Hour(s).
echo $difference->i; //return the difference in Minute(s)
echo $difference->s; //return the difference in Second(s).
```

Comment: Ok, I tried this. So on the page I log in on, I have the 

$_SESSION['loginTime'] = new DateTime(date('y-m-d h:m:s'));

and the page I want the total time logged in to appear on, I have the rest (minus the echos for years, months and days) 

I must have done something wrong, it doesn't seem to be counting the time right. Sometimes it goes up by 30 seconds or more, and then starts going backwards. Any idea where I went wrong there?

Comment: `DateTime(date('y-m-d h:i:s')`

Comment: I would add a check to see if it is already started (so it doesn't keep resetting every time the page is accessed: if (!isset($_SESSION['loginTime'] )) $_SESSION['loginTime'] = new DateTime(date('y-m-d h:m:s'));

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using php you would set a session value with the current time,  then retrieve the value from that session variable on the other page (where you show the time). 
On the login

```
session_start(); //immediately after <?php tag
$_SESSION ['timer'] = time();
```

and on the page you are retrieving it

```
session_start ();
$ timeSinceLogin =( time () - $_SESSION ['timer']) /60; //time in minutes.
```

Don't forget that

```
session_start();
```

immediately after the php opening tag on every page you are using session data.

Comment: if you need days/ months/ years you can use `echo (time() - $_SESSION['timer']);` for seconds, `echo number_format(time() - $_SESSION['timer']) /60, 2);` for minutes with 2 decimal places, `echo number_format(time() - $_SESSION['timer']) /3600, 2);` for hours with 2 decimal places etc. Unless you set the session expiration for longer than the default life-of-window then I don't see the point in converting it to a datetime and using the object- are your users really going to leave the browser window open for months? That's why I stuck to timestamp.